# What information do I use to test credit card transactions with PayPal Payments Pro

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've spent about an hour trying to figure out what information to use to test credit card transactions in the PayPal Sandbox environment. No matter what I try I get the "Invalid Data This transaction cannot be processed." error. I'm using the Classic API.

I created a personal verified account with a Visa credit card in my developer account but the credit card information generated by the system yield the same error. Here's a screen of the account:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s141/sh/e2a7147c-9cfb-4587-814d-13fdd97d1c29/a1e3d97e505071d6f927a71195f06f2f

After searching I found this post https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sandbox/how-test-sandbox-paypal-using-pay-credit-card  I then logged into that Sandbox account, went to Profile > Credit/Debit Cards > Add a Card, chose Visa but the credit card number wasn't pre-populate as I had hoped. Here's a screen:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s141/sh/5cfce2b8-da2f-4147-abf5-5d742995b3ca/6d6e1541cbb5809e0e14972d2d81f4bb

I'm really at a loss now. Any help would be really appreciated :)

P.S. I've already tried the cliche test numbers like 4444333322221111 but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using some of these test credit card numbers.  If it still does not work can you provide the API request you are sending, and the full API response you are getting back and I will look it up on my side and see whats causing the issue.

Visa Test Card Numbers - You can use 123 for the CVV2, and any valid future date for the exp date.

4916064324171157
4916884530887530
4024007135477981
4556908617562966
4929631921286961
4916781542208590
4502888845652562
4532975922625589
4024007116051706
4485137169794373

Comment: Oh jeez, I just found the problem. Sorry for wasting your time >< It turns out the issue had nothing to do with the credit card information. The error I was getting was 10747 "The merchant entered an IP address that was in an invalid format. The IP address must be in a format such as 123.456.123.456.".  I was running the tests locally and my box was sending the IPAddress field as ::1.  I have no idea how I overlooked that. After deploying to a staging server I was able to place a credit card order using the information from one of the buyer accounts in my developer box.

Comment: How do you know that it is 123?